# Loop over DOMDocument

Tags: php, loops, domdocument

I am following the suggestion from this question Robust, [Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php/321963#321963), about parsing html that may be malformed with [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Is there any easy way to loop over the parsed document?  So I would like to loop over html like this.

```
$html='<ul>
         <li>value1</li>
         <li>value1</li>
         <li>value3
            <p>subvalue</p>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <p>hello world</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
???
foreach (??? as $node)
{
  print $node->nodeName.':'.$node->nodeValue;
}
```

And get results somewhat like this.

```
 ul:
 li:value1
 li:value2
 li:value3
 p:subvalue
 p:hello world
```

Using `$doc->childNodes` by itself doesn't really do what I want.  Since it doesn't seem to go down to lower branches in the tree.  I used the code suggested by [halfdan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909849/loop-over-domdocument/2909863#2909863) and I get results like this.

```
html:
html:value1
         value1
         value3
            subvalue

        hello world
```

Comment: DOM objects can (but don't always) have a property called $childNodes that you can iterate over.  You can check for the presence or otherwise of this property with the hasChildNodes() method.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
showDOMNode($doc);

function showDOMNode(DOMNode $domNode) {
    foreach ($domNode->childNodes as $node)
    {
        print $node->nodeName.':'.$node->nodeValue;
        if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
            showDOMNode($node);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to be more clear.  I don't believe `$doc->childNodes` by itself does what I want.  Basically I want to visit each node in the tree, not just see all nodes at one level.

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues with elements that had c data, where even elements that didn't have children where returning that they did.

I am not sure why it was.

The work around I found was to change

```
if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        showDOMNode($node);
    }
```

to

```
if($node->childNodes->length != 1) {
        showDOMNode($node);
    }
```

And the code now works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to walk the tree as follow:

```
function next_node($node)
{
    if($node->firstChild != null)
    {
        return $node->firstChild;
    }

    if($node->nextSibling != null)
    {
        return $node->nextSibling;
    }

    for($node = $node->parentNode; $node != null; $node = $node->parentNode)
    {
        if($node->nextSibling != null)
        {
            return $node->nextSibling;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

for($node = $doc; $node != null; $node = next_node($node))
{
    // handle node (read-only mode, if you need read-write
    // you have to save all the nodes in an array and then
    // use that array
    //
    ...
}
```

This works for most documents, however it looks like at times the `parentNode` is somehow not correctly set and the `next_node()` function ends up returning the wrong information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and the following code:

```
<?php
require_once 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

function iterateHtmlElements($html)
{
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    $dom->set_callback('handleElement');
    $dom->__toString();
    echo "\n";
}

function handleElement(simple_html_dom_node $elem)
{
    if($elem->tag == 'text') {
        echo $elem->innertext();
    }
    else {
        echo "\n" . $elem->tag . ": ";
    }
}

$html='<ul>
         <li>value1</li>
         <li>value1</li>
         <li>value3
            <p>subvalue</p>
         </li>
        </ul>
        <p>hello world</p>';
iterateHtmlElements($html);
```

It works exactly as expected. I checked it with the input you provided and got the following results:

```
> php test2.php

ul:
li: value1
li: value1
li: value3
p: subvalue
p: hello world
```

Comment: Does not work for me, str_get_html just returns false.

Comment: Ended up using https://stackoverflow.com/a/14554381/2897386

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look through some HTML tag, feel free:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($a);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tr");
$xml = "";
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // you can extract here content of some <td> tag
    $xml .= $doc->saveXML($node);
}
var_dump(htmlentities($xml));
```