# PHP find URLS in string and make links. If not already in link

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to find URLs in strings where the link is not already in a link

My Current Code:

```
$text = "http://www.google.com is a great website. Visit <a href='http://www.google.com' >http://google.com</a>"
$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";


if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
   $links = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $_page['content']['external_links']);

}
```

The problem with this is it is returning the link twice (This is what it is returning):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a> is a great website. Visit <a href='<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a>' ><a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com</a></a>
```

Comment: If you only want to compute links that are not already in a <a> tag, then could probably edit your regex so that you can check if your link isn't surrounded by simple or double quotes

Comment: it isn't so simple because an url can be in several places in an html document (in an href attribute, in a src attribute, in a DTD, or in a javascript code). So a better way consists to extract text nodes of your document that are not a child of a link node (or script/style node) and to make the replacement.

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption here that a URL you want to match would be followed by either whitespace, punctuation, or be at the end of a line. Of course if there is something like `<a href="site">http://url </a>` then it won't work quite as well. If you expect to encounter that, then first replace all `\s+</a>` with `</a>`

```
$text = "http://www.google.com is a great website. Visit <a href='http://www.google.com' >http://google.com</a>, and so is ftp://ftp.theweb.com";
$reg_exUrl = "/((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})([\s.,;\?\!]|$)/";

if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $matches)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $match) {
        $text = str_replace(
            $match,
            '<a href="'.$matches[1][$i].'" rel="nofollow">'.$matches[1][$i].'</a>'.$matches[3][$i],
            $text
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

http://www.google.com is a great website. Visit http://www.google.com' >http://google.com, and so is ftp://ftp.theweb.com

Comment: this doesnt add nofollow to the url that is already a html link

Comment: @GillesMisslin I suppose I could take a new look at this. What text did you try it with?

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it. `preg_replace_callback` is the right function to use here.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing it would be to use `DOMDocument` to parse your HTML code. Then iterate recursively over children. Skip nodes that have tagName equal to "a". Then analyse the `textNodes` and if they are not part of  node, then replace the `textNode` with a node and put the `textNode` value in it.

Finally use `saveHTML` to get back html string.

manual about loading html:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Stack Overflow ticket about iterating over childNodes:
[Loop over DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909849/loop-over-domdocument)

---

Here is another quick version for your specific case:

```
<?php

$input = "http://www.google.com is a great website. Visit <a href='http://www.google.com' >http://google.com</a>";

$output = preg_replace_callback("/(^|[^\"'>])(https?:\/\/[^ \n\r]+)/s",function($in){

    $url = $in[2];
    return "<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"$url\">$url</a>";
}, $input);
```

As you can see, we are using trick regex to look for http/https links that do not seem to be part of a tag. Note, that this will not work for cases like `<b>https://google.com</b>`. If you need more advanced solution, you should either go with DOMDocument or alternatively you can check the text before the each occurrence of the https? marker.

---

And here is an even better version, as suggested by [@mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa):

```
<?php

$input = "http://www.google.com is a great website. Visit <a href='http://www.google.com' >http://google.com</a>";

$output = preg_replace_callback("~<a[^>]+>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(https?:\/\/\S+)~i",function($match){
    return sprintf("<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"%s\">%s</a>", $match[1], $match[1]);
}, $input);
```

it uses ultra magic regular expression syntax with (*SKIP)(*FAIL) and a bit more elegant sprintf for building the replacement value.

Comment: Using a pattern delimiter other than `/` will prevent needing to escape literal forward slashes in your pattern. The `s` pattern modifier is pointless because you don't have `.` anywhere in your pattern.  `[^ \n\r]` can be replaced with `\S` (and will include tabs in the excluded character list).  Using `sprintf()` will help to clean up your `return` data and allow you to use more modern arrow function syntax.  Case-insensitivity might be a reasonable feature for general use. I would probably use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to explicitly exclude existing tags.

Comment: sounds good, go ahead add another answer with your suggested improvements!

Comment: I was going to, then realized that I already did. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53346522/2943403

Comment: (*SKIP)(*FAIL) is really cool idea. I noticed that you used that on single line chunks with one occurrence. does this also works properly with multiline input and multiple occurrences?

Comment: It sure does. https://3v4l.org/DQK75

Comment: Added another solution variation based on your input.

Comment: Sharpened: `preg_replace("~<a\b[^>]+>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|https?://\S+~i", '<a rel="nofollow" href="$0">$0</a>', $input)` (untested)