# PHP Regex convert plain text URL to link unless it already is

Tags: php, regex

I have a php string $tweet that looks like this...

```
This is a sample tweet https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3
```

But sometimes it can look like this...

```
This is a sample tweet <a href="https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3">https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3</a>
```

I am wanting to convert all https://tr.co links to actual a href links unless they are already in that format.

I know I can convert the links with Regex but can I also check if they are already a link using it as well?

Comment: Can each string have mulitple URLs?

Comment: `if(strpos($string, '<a href="https://tr.co"') === false){ // Convert with regex } else { // leave it alone }` - Just a basic idea to get you going on this.

Comment: Yes it could potentially have multiple URLs

Comment: On multiple URLs my solution won't work. It will return false positives if one link is plain text and the other an element.

Comment: @fightstarr20, aren't you looking for a regex to do it? what about my solution bellow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into incredibly sophisticated syntax trying to match bits and pieces of a url, you can disqualify already-tagged urls using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and then only match the urls from your domain.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z9ocu)) ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rQQJUw/6))

```
$tweets = [
    'This is a sample tweet https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3',
    'This is a sample tweet <a href="https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3">https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3</a>',
    'This is a sample tweet https://example.com/sdfhnjn3',
    'This is a sample tweet <a href="https://example.com/sdfhnjn3">https://example.com/sdfhnjn3</a>'
];

var_export(preg_replace('~<a [^>]+>.*?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|https?://(?:www)?tr\.co/\S*~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $tweets));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'This is a sample tweet <a href="https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3">https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3</a>',
  1 => 'This is a sample tweet <a href="https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3">https://tr.co/sdfhnjn3</a>',
  2 => 'This is a sample tweet https://example.com/sdfhnjn3',
  3 => 'This is a sample tweet <a href="https://example.com/sdfhnjn3">https://example.com/sdfhnjn3</a>',
)
```

*only the first element was actually updated, the others did not qualify.

If case insensitivity is required, add `i` after the pattern-ending `~`.

Answer (score 2):

To match and replace **only the url that are not yet links** try this regex: `~(?<!href=['"])https?://[\w/._\-&?]*(?!</a>)(?=[^\w/._\-&])~gs`.

You can see the demo here: https://regex101.com/r/BF8HBO/1.

Then use it with `preg_replace`:

```
$string = preg_replace('~(?<!href=['"])https?://[\w/._\-&?]*(?!</a>)(?=[^\w/._\-&])~gs', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string);`;
```

> **Note:** check the substitution panel also in regex101 to see the links are placed only if not yet there.

---

**DETAILS:**

- I use `~` as a delimiter as it is less frequently encountered in regex body so you won't need to escape as often as with `/`
- `(?<!href=['"])` this is a negative lookbehind that makes sure the link is not preceded with `href=` and either `'` or `"`
- `https?://[\w/._\-&?]*` matches the link starting with `http://` or `https://`
- `[\w/._\-&?]*` this matches any alphanumeric char or one of those `/._?&-` the litterals that can usually appear in a link
- `(?!</a>)` this is a negative lookahead making sure that the link is not followed with an ending `</a>`
- `(?=[^\w/._\-&])` this is a positive lookahead that makes sure the next character after the link is not one of those `/._-&` nor a alphanumeric char (otherwise they should be part of the link)

> **Another note:** PHP has a good regex engine (PCRE) that allows lookarounds and especially lookbehinds! that is not the case of some other languages such as javascript unfortunately. But there is always a (complicated) workaround! :)
>
> also lookbehinds must have a fixed width characters unlike lookaheads.

Answer (score 1):

This code will replace any url in the supplied $message with a link to that url

```
$message = preg_replace('$(\s|^)(https?://[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+)(?![^<>]*>)$i', ' <a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a> ', $message." ");
```

In fact, you can also convert url that doesn't have the protocol (http) part, as long as it starts with www, and it could pass for a valid url.

```
$message = preg_replace('$(\s|^)(www\.[a-z0-9_./?=&-]+)(?![^<>]*>)$i', '<a target="_blank" href="http://$2"  target="_blank">$2</a> ', $message." ");
```