# Get remote page complete contents and display at site

Tags: php, jquery, dom, curl, file-get-contents

I simply want to load above page's complete contents and display using php.
I tried below method but it did not work.

```
$url = "http://www.officialcerts.com/exams.asp?examcode=101";

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$output = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$DOM = new DOMDocument;

$DOM->loadHTML( $output);
```

How do I walk the Document that loadHTML produced?

Comment: `did not work` is not a proper problem description. As for loading full page; you can run into numerous resource path problems if relative url's are used in source

Comment: Where do you set the value of `$items`?  ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909849/loop-over-domdocument for examples of how to walk the DOM Document Tree that `loadHTML` built -- well, maybe built, you don't check the return value of `loadHTML` to see if it worked or not....

Answer (score -1):

If you like to display the page as is, Use a frame to load your page, this is the simplest way ever:

```
<frame src="URL">
```

[Frame tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_frame_src.asp)

Comment: i think you did not see what i am trying to achieve. using html frame tag is not a way to do it.

Comment: [`<frame>` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame)... are you sure you didn't mean `<iframe>`?

Comment: i don't want to use <iframe> , i want to fetch the given sites contents using curl() or file_get_contents method and display on page.