# Split all html tags into a array

Tags: php, domdocument

Let's suppose that I have this code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>    
<body>
<div id="x">Hello</div>
<p>world</p>
<h1>my name</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And I need to extract all html tags and put inside a array, like this:

```
'0' => '<!DOCTYPE html>',
'1' => '<html>',
'2' => '<head>',
'3' => '<meta charset="UTF-8">',
'4' => '<title>Title of the document</title>',
'5' => '</head>',
'6' => '<body>',
'7' => '<div id="x">Hello</div>',
'8' => '<p>world</p>',
'9' => '<h1>my name</h1>',
....
```

in my case I have no need to get all the existing content within a tag , for me only catch the beginning of each tag was already very good.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following solution with `preg_match_all` function:

```
$html_content = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>    
<body>
<div id="x">Hello</div>
<p>world</p>
<h1>my name</h1>
</body>
</html>';

preg_match_all("/\<\w[^<>]*?\>([^<>]+?\<\/\w+?\>)?|\<\/\w+?\>/i", $html_content, $matches);
// <!DOCTYPE html> is standardized document type definition and is not a tag

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <html>
    [1] => <head>
    [2] => <meta charset="UTF-8">
    [3] => <title>Title of the document</title>
    [4] => </head>
    [5] => <body>
    [6] => <div id="x">Hello</div>
    [7] => <p>world</p>
    [8] => <h1>my name</h1>
    [9] => </body>
    [10] => </html>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go is to load the HTML into a DOMDocument class and iterate through the nodes.

See related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20025973/2870598