# PHP split HTML string into array of parent elements similar to jquery .children()

Tags: php

I have a string of HTML in my database saved from a textarea.

The string looks like this:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Praesent sit amet dolor et nunc dignissim venenatis.</li>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <span style="font-size: 1rem;">Mauris id sagittis libero, nec vulputate justo. Maecenas nec laoreet ante.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span style="font-size: 1rem;">ggrer</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <li>hjhrttr</li>
    <li>Sed pulvinar eget nibh vel sollicitudin. Curabitur nec lacus mi.&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Phasellus eleifend id mauris a pharetra. Mauris id mi at tortor rhoncus posuere ut sed metus.</li>
</ul>
<p style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;">
    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;">
    Donec nec nisl metus. Pellentesque vel molestie dolor.
</p>
<p style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;">
    Aenean pharetra luctus dignissim.
</p>
```

I need an array which consists of the HTML from each parent element. In jQuery, I was able to achieve this by placing the HTML in an element on the page and using jQuery's `children()` function.

```
<div id="code_container">{{ html_entity_decode(@data['contents']) }}</div>
<script>
    var draft = $('#code_container');
    console.log(draft.children());
</script>
```

Which gives me a result like this:

[image]

However, I'd prefer to stick to PHP rather than having to involve JavaScript at all. I've looked around answers on SO, but they all seem to put nested HTML in it's own array element instead of just the top level elements.

My expected results look like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => "<p style=\"margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;\">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>",

    [1] => "<ul>
        <li>Praesent sit amet dolor et nunc dignissim venenatis.</li>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <span style=\"font-size: 1rem;\">Mauris id sagittis libero, nec vulputate justo. Maecenas nec laoreet ante.</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span style=\"font-size: 1rem;\">ggrer</span>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <li>hjhrttr</li>
        <li>Sed pulvinar eget nibh vel sollicitudin. Curabitur nec lacus mi.&nbsp;</li>
        <li>Phasellus eleifend id mauris a pharetra. Mauris id mi at tortor rhoncus posuere ut sed metus.</li>
    </ul>",

    [2] => "<p style=\"margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;\">
        Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>",

    [3] => "<p style=\"margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;\">
        Donec nec nisl metus. Pellentesque vel molestie dolor.
    </p>",

    [4] => "<p style=\"margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px;\">
        Aenean pharetra luctus dignissim. Donec tincidunt mattis dolor.
    </p>"
)
```

Comment: Might have to resort to a DOM Parser (domdocument) like library to help out. Writing up one yourself may be time consuming, even though all you want is the top level blocks.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I'm fine with using a DOM parser. I tried to do this myself but have no experience with that library. All the answers I could find don't only split at the top level, they also split out the nested elements.

Comment: Ah, right, I see, the db content is just the html chunks (not a full html document). Maybe  first wrap the content you have in a basic block to call the document: `'<html>'. $yourdata_from_db .'</html>'` ... then it may let you grab all "first elements"? Total guess, I'm not super familiar with domDocument either :D

Comment: @IncredibleHat Interesting idea. I will try that out

Comment: I think using regular expression would help!

Comment: @MiraSoft I did try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543437/5827005) regex answer, but it splits nested elements as well.