# PHP beginner needs a hand with foreach loop

Tags: php

Real php beginner here, sorry for the basic questions, but I didn't find any solution.

1. question:
   I am looping through the children of a page in processwire. I got help in the processwire forum with this code:

   ```
             <?php foreach ($page->children() as $product): ?>

           <div class='single-product-wrapper'>

             <?php $thumb = $img->size(100, 100); ?>
             <img src="<?php echo $product->thumb->first()->url; ?> "/>
             <p><?php echo $product->inhalt1; ?></p>

           </div>

         <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```

But, when I try to write it in regular PHP, I don't see the images on my website
What am I writing wrong? I think the following php is the same as the above.

```
   <div class='single-product-wrapper'>

            <?php foreach ($page->children() as $product){
              echo $product->img->first()->url;
              echo $product->inhalt1; 


            }

            ?>

          </div>
```

2. question:

How do I write a resize of the images into thumbnails in shorthand php?
Now I get the fullsize images on the page.

Thanks a lot
Jakob

Comment: What is content of `$page`?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/2909849/5104748

Answer (score 1):

1- You are not seeing the image on your web page because you are printing only the URL of the image. But you are not saying the browser to print it.

```
// This line will print only the URL
echo $product->img->first()->url;

// but this will print the img tag with the URL. Browser will show the image
<img src="<?php echo $product->thumb->first()->url; ?>">
```

2 - You can pass a small size on img tag as height and weigth atributes. Or better use CSS to format the image size